# VB.NET - Combine rows in DataTable based on shared value

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to combine rows in a `DataTable` based on their shared ID. The table data looks something like this:

```
Member | ID   | Assistant | Content
---------------------------------------------
16     | 1234 | jkaufman  | 1/1/2015 - stuff1
16     | 1234 | jkaufman  | 1/2/2015 - stuff2
16     | 4321 | mhatfield | 1/3/2015 - stuff3
16     | 4321 | mhatfield | 1/4/2015 - stuff4
16     | 4321 | mhatfield | 1/5/2015 - stuff5
16     | 5678 | psmith    | 1/6/2015 - stuff6
```

I want to combine rows based on matching IDs. There are two steps I could use some clarification on. The first is merging the rows. The second is combining the Content columns so that the contents aren't lost. For the example above, here's what I want:

```
Member | ID   | Assistant | Content
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16     | 1234 | jkaufman  | 1/1/2015 - stuff1 \r\n 1/2/2015 - stuff2
16     | 4321 | mhatfield | 1/3/2015 - stuff3 \r\n 1/4/2015 - stuff4 \r\n 1/5/2015 - stuff5
16     | 5678 | psmith    | 1/6/2015 - stuff6
```

My eventual goal is copy the `DataTable` to an Excel spreadsheet so I'm not sure sure if the `\r\n` is the correct newline character but that's the least of my concerns at this point.

Here's my code right now (EDIT: updated to current code):

```
Dim tmpRow As DataRow
dtFinal = dt.Clone()

Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < dt.Rows.Count
    tmpRow = dtFinal.NewRow()
    tmpRow.ItemArray = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray.Clone()
    Dim j As Integer = i + 1
    While j <= dt.Rows.Count
        If j = dt.Rows.Count Then 'if we've iterated off the end of the datset
            i = j
            Exit While
        End If
        If dt.Rows(i).Item("ID") = dt.Rows(j).Item("ID") Then 'if we've found another entry for this id
            'append change to tmpRow
            tmpRow.Item("Content") = tmpRow.Item("Content").ToString & Environment.NewLine & dt.Rows(j).Item("Content").ToString
        Else 'if we've run out of entries to combine
            i = j
            Exit While
        End If

        j += 1
    End While
    'add our combined row to the final result
    dtFinal.ImportRow(tmpRow)
End While
```

When I export the final table to Excel, the spreadsheet is blank so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: a datatable row has one row of information.  it sounds like you are trying to combine 2 rows into one.

Comment: Basically. I'm trying to combine multiple rows that share all but one column into one row with all the information.

Comment: I've edited the original post to reflect some changes I've made to the code. Hopefully it helps point toward a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see various problems with your approach (with both versions; but the second one seems better). That's why I have preferred to write a whole working code to help transmit my ideas clearly.

```
    Dim dtFinal As DataTable = New DataTable
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        dtFinal.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType)
    Next

    Dim oldRow As Integer = -1
    Dim row As Integer = -1
    While oldRow < dt.Rows.Count - 1

        dtFinal.Rows.Add()
        row = row + 1

        oldRow = oldRow + 1
        Dim curID As String = dt.Rows(oldRow)(1).ToString()
        Dim lastCol As String = ""
        While (oldRow < dt.Rows.Count AndAlso dt.Rows(oldRow)(1).ToString() = curID)
            lastCol = lastCol & dt.Rows(oldRow)(3).ToString() & Environment.NewLine
            oldRow = oldRow + 1
        End While

        oldRow = oldRow - 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            dtFinal.Rows(row)(i) = dt.Rows(oldRow)(i)
        Next
        dtFinal.Rows(row)(3) = lastCol

    End While
```

Note that trying to come up with the most "elegant" solution or to maximise the given in-built functionalities might not be the best way to face certain situations. In the problem you propose, for example, I think that it is better going step by step (and reducing code size/improving elegance only after a properly working version is in place). This is the kind of code I have tried to create here: a simple one delivering what is expected (I think that this is the exact functionality you want; in any case, bear in mind that I am including a simplistic code which you are expected to take as a mere help to understand the point).

Comment: My real DataTable had a few more columns than I showed here so I had to change the `For i As Integer = 0 To 2` to `For i As Integer = 0 To dtFinal.Columns.Count`. Otherwise, the logic is spot on. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam You are welcome. In any case and as said above, note that I wrote the code as a sample helping me to quickly transmit various ideas, not as a comprehensive final solution.

Answer (score 1):

I find the VB syntax clunky compared to how it would be in C#, but you may prefer this Linq with grouping solution:

```
Dim merge = (From rw In dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)()
            Group rw By
                New With {.fld1 = rw(0)}.fld1,
                New With {.fld2 = rw(1)}.fld2,
                New With {.fld3 = rw(2)}.fld3 Into Group).
                    Select(Function(x)
                               Return New With {.Member = x.fld1,
                                                .ID = x.fld2,
                                                .Assistant = x.fld3,
                                                .Content = String.Join("", x.Group.Select(Function(y)
                                                                                              Return String.Join("", y.ItemArray)
                                                                                          End Function))}
                           End Function)
```

[image]